# Issue with PySpark PCA methods

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, error-handling, pca

For a project, I need to implement an image size reduction with the help of Spark (PySpark more exactly).
For the first part of the project, I use this tutorial: https://docs.databricks.com/applications/machine-learning/preprocess-data/transfer-learning-tensorflow.html

It allows to process the images (in 224x224 format) and to retrieve the features using the first layers of the VGG16 neural network.
So I get an array of this type (for an image here) which is flatten:

```
features = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0...]
```

Only, when I apply the PCA, I get this error that I don't know how to solve:

```
IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Column features must be of type struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>> but was actually array<float>
```

I understand that the structure is not good but I don't see how to fix this error...